# Custom python REPL with fifos

Tags: python, fifo

Is it possible to make a custom REPL (for e.g. python) with two fifos?

#### Explanation of the problem

Suppose I have two fifos `in` and `out`. I have three terminals.

1. In the first I want to run commands that output python code to `in`. For example

   `echo "print(1+2)" > in
   echo "a = 3" > in
   echo "b = 4" > in
   // wait some time # usual comments break SO formatting
   echo "print(a*b)" > in`
2. The second just runs `cat out`. The result should be something like

   `3
   // wait a little time <-- of course this is not real output
   12`
3. The third should read `in` run the lines through `python` and print the result to `out` just like in a usual interactive python session.

#### Attempt at a solution / further remarks

- Just running `python in >out` in the third terminal does not work. It terminates after the first line is written to `in`, the second terminal will only print the `3`.
- Writing a wrapper that tries to run lines from `in` through `eval` does not work, because I need to be able to parse lines like `import sys`, or the likes.
- All in all, I really want the behaviour of the standard REPL of python, except that I do not want to be sitting at the keyboard and putting in lines, one by one. I want to be able to change the input and output channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the [code](https://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html) module? You probably want to subclass `code.InteractiveConsole` and override its `write` method to write into your `out` FIFO, and have an outer loop that reads lines from the `in` FIFO and calls the `push` method with each line.

I haven't tested this but even if it doesn't work exactly like I've suggested your solution will no doubt nevertheless make use of the `code` module.

Comment: Awesome, that will probably help me in finding a solution! Thanks for the pointer.